# How to make an array of character in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make an array of character. I get this code and get error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"boolean.h"

const char *skillNames[8];
skillNames[0] = "Darth Vader";
skillNames[1] = "Han Solo";
skillNames[2] = "Master Yoda";
skillNames[3] = "Luke Skywalker";
skillNames[4] = "Obi Wan Kenobi";
skillNames[5] = "Chewbacca";
skillNames[6] = "Emperor Palpatine";
skillNames[7] = "Princess Leia";
```

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: If the code you show is a proper [mre] and the actual code you have, you seem to have forgotten (or missed) that normal statements can only be inside functions.

Comment: `const char *skillNames[] = {"Darth Vader", "Han Solo", ....};`

Comment: Eugene's comment above is the only thing that's going to work, short of moving your code into a function, calling malloc to allocate memory for your array, and setting the array elements individually with `strcpy`.  You can do all that, but if you don't need the array to be editable, Eugene's solution is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"boolean.h"

int main() {
    const char *skillNames[8];
    skillNames[0] = "Darth Vader";
    skillNames[1] = "Han Solo";
    skillNames[2] = "Master Yoda";
    skillNames[3] = "Luke Skywalker";
    skillNames[4] = "Obi Wan Kenobi";
    skillNames[5] = "Chewbacca";
    skillNames[6] = "Emperor Palpatine";
    skillNames[7] = "Princess Leia";
}
```

Put it inside a `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the initialization syntax. You don't even need to mention the size of the array:

```
const char *skillNames[] = {
    "Darth Vader",    "Han Solo",  "Master Yoda",       "Luke Skywalker",
    "Obi Wan Kenobi", "Chewbacca", "Emperor Palpatine", "Princess Leia",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `main()` function and replace the `#include"boolean.h"` with `#include<stdbool.h>`. See if that fixes the error or not.

The full code can be like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
int main()
{
    const char *skillNames[8];
    skillNames[0] = "Darth Vader";
    skillNames[1] = "Han Solo";
    skillNames[2] = "Master Yoda";
    skillNames[3] = "Luke Skywalker";
    skillNames[4] = "Obi Wan Kenobi";
    skillNames[5] = "Chewbacca";
    skillNames[6] = "Emperor Palpatine";
    skillNames[7] = "Princess Leia";
}
```